# htaccess redirect 301 without a folder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

i'm trying to do

- redirect a site from `a.example` to `b.example`
- folder `a.example/c/` must not redirect
- `a.example/test.php` must be redirected to `a.example/c/test.php`

i try this `.htaccess`  :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule !^c($|/) https://b.example/ [L,R=301]

Redirect 301 /test.php https://www.a.example/c/test.php
```

but this second 301 redirect doesn't redirect?

Comment: Probably because your RewriteRule interferes - if `/rssblog.php` was requested, then the negated condition of the RewriteRule is of course true. Try changing the order of both directives. If that does not help, then I would do both things using a RewriteRule, rather than mixing different directives.

Comment: Thank you! I try to change the order but nothing is changed...... :( thanx for your time

Comment: You used example domains/URLs in your examples, but (what looks like) actually domains/URLs in your code block - how confusing! You should stick to the same "examples" throughout. "redirect a site from a.com to b.com" - to the homepage/root of `b.com` or are you wanting to redirect to the same URL-path at `b.com`?

Comment: sorry but someone modify my code...

RewriteRule !^blog($|/) https://example1.com/ [L,R=301]
Redirect 301 /test.php https://www.example.com/blog/test.php


i need to :
redirect a site from example to example1`
folder example/blog/ must not redirect
example/test.php must be redirected to example/blog/test.php

Comment: Yes, that "someone" was _me_. I exemplified your code to match your example (like for like - it does the same thing). If you think it is incorrect then please edit your question. Do not post large unformatted code fragments in comments as this is unreadable. Use example hostnames as defined in RFC2606. eg. use the `.example` TLD when dealing with multiple domains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first mod_rewrite `RewriteRule` directive redirects *everything* that does not start `blog` to `b.example`. This will naturally redirect `/test.php` as well. Changing the order of these rules will make no difference since `Redirect` is a mod_alias directive and is processed later<sup>**1**</sup> regardless of the order of the directives. (<sup>**1**</sup>earlier on "LiteSpeed", opposite to Apache.)

You would need to do something like this instead, using mod_rewrite throughout and reversing the order of the two rules:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^test\.php$ /c/$0 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule !^c($|/) https://b.example/ [L,R=301]
```

This does assume that the second domain (`b.example`) points to a different server.

The `$0` backreference in the *substitution* string in the first rule contains the full URL-path that is matched by the `RewriteRule` *pattern*, ie. `test.php` in this example (saves repetition).

Test with a 302 (temporary) redirect first to avoid potential caching issues. You will need to clear your browser cache before testing.

Comment: sorry but someone modify my code...

RewriteRule !^blog($|/) https://example1.com/ [L,R=301]
Redirect 301 /test.php https://www.example.com/blog/test.php


i need to :
redirect a site from example to example1`
folder example/blog/ must not redirect
example/test.php must be redirected to example/blog/test.php

Comment: @simone71 The code in my answer matches your example (and follows the same pattern as your code sample). Have you tried it? I believe this answers your question. (You obviously need to substiute `rssblog\.php` for `test\.php` and `/blog/` for `/c/` etc.) And, as mentioned, you will need to clear your browser cache before testing.

Comment: thanx a lot!

is the first time that I use stackoverflow and it's fantastic thanx for your time